# Yii swiftmailer fails to work in live server

Tags: php, yii, yii2, swiftmailer

Am using yii2 and i have setup a mailer as follows

```
  <?php
  return [
   'components' => [
  ....
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'mygmailpassword',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
        ],
    ],
],
```

];

The above works perfectly in localhost but fails when i upload to the live server i always get an error of bad credentials

The error is

```
Swift_TransportException

 Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8     
Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at

535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 
r199sm3707144wme.1 - gsmtp
```

"

What could be wrong,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this config for gmail  (and work)

```
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'myname.mylast@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'mypass',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
```

Comment: even after adding the port as 587 the same error still pops up

Comment: The message  tell .. problem  with username  or password .. check the credential  too

Comment: But on the local wampserver everything works just fine, the credentials are  okay: they are my gmail email and password. are there different trnsport options for yii except from gmail

Comment: Could be that the server don't permit .. the redirect to another mail server .. check if the server/provider  use a proper mail services ..

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI  you changed also the encryption to tls ??

Comment: I found out that the server did not permit redirrection to other mail servers i had to configure a maier based on the domain nameservers, Thanks